# Horizontal html line underneath text

Tags: html, text, line

I want to make an horizontal line in `html`, that is located underneath a word. Like so:

Example
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

How I do this?

Comment: Could you provide us a more concrete example? What sort of elements are you working with (divs/spans/etc). What sort of line are you looking for? What are your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use text-decoration for it.

```
p.sometext {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Or you can try border for this.

```
div.sometext {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #DDD;
}
```

Comment: Using `text-decoration` is just the same as a `<u>` element, so that code is wrong. Having a `border-bottom` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just asking to put a horizontal rule underneath a header. If so, use the `<hr>` element.
 **Example:**

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1><hr>
```